# Play a success sound ONLY when Activity is complete

Tags: java, android

I have created an app that you could share images with them. I have set a notification sound when the sharing process is done. However, if I hit Cancel/Back buttons, the sound still plays. 
In my code below, I have set a share button, once you click on it, you can share a bitmap of the image through the basic sharing app of android.
How can I set the sound to ONLY play when the sharing is complete. 
Thanks,
Safi

Here's my code:

```
shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(animTranslate);
            shareDigitalCard();
        }
    });

private void shareDigitalCard() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MyMenu.this,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            makeStorageRequest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        Bitmap viewBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPager.getWidth(), 
        mPager.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       viewBmp.setDensity(mPager.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(viewBmp);
        //mPager.layout(0, 0 , mPager.getLayoutParams().width, mPager.getLayoutParams().height);
        mPager.draw(canvas);

        path = String.valueOf(saveTempBitmap(viewBmp));

        shareImage(path);
    }
}

private void shareImage(String file) {
    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    File imageFileToShare = new File(file);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"),123);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 123){
        if (isSoundEnable) {
            MediaPlayer player = null;
            if (player == null) {
                player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.success);
                final MediaPlayer finalPlayer = player;
                player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        stopPlayer(finalPlayer);
                    }
                });
            }
            player.start();
        }

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "An Error Has Occured !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get this event. The sharing procedure depends on the other App and you haven't any control or result from it. What you know is just you have send an Intent to a specific App, but what it does it's all up to it.